# Does Fate or Savage Worlds have a prebuilt, low-magic, gritty, fantasy campaign setting which feature a single big issue?

Tags: game-recommendation, savage-worlds, fate, campaign-settings, fantasy

I'm looking for a fantasy campaign setting with the following elements:

- Savage Worlds or Fate. But I'm open to hacks or others rules systems that match this requisites: Rules light, narrative flavor (mechanically) and pdf material.
- The big issue: Something relevant is happening in the setting, something that make it singular, unique. Something that could influence the whole world. A menace in the horizon;
- Dark, gritty or low/subtle magic: The setting must have some of this flavor. It's not necessary to have all of them.
- Pre-built: I prefer to have access to ready to use material.

Comment: Are you looking for how to *generate* these in fate? Or pre-built ones? What issues are you interested in?

Comment: Hi, i´m looking for a pre-built setting. For Fate i´m aware of Freeport, for example.

Comment: This could benefit from narrowing down, as this description fits most of the Savage Worlds campaigns that come to mind.

Answer (score 14):

There are a number of *Savage Worlds settings* that fit some or all of the criteria you are looking for, and all are available in print and PDF:

## **[Evernight](https://www.peginc.com/product-category/evernight/)** by Pinnacle Entertainment Group

> The world of Tarth was a bright and shining jewel. The Great Race Wars were long over, the people were free, and true evil had been scattered to the dark bowels of the earth. The King of Valusia sat upon his throne and ruled his peaceful valley and its honest citizens with a firm yet fair grip.
>
> The future of Tarth was bright. Until they came. And the light went out forever. Evernight™ is a very different kind of dark fantasy setting. This 144-page PDF book provides a complete scripted campaign, from before the arrival of the mysterious and terrifying Masters to the epic and bloody finish. Player characters start as Novices in a familiar fantasy world of elves, dwarves, orcs, and men. They finish as Heroic adventurers in a land draped in eternal night and overwhelming horror.

- *The Big Issue:* The Masters from a hellish dimension are going to, and eventually do, invade the world and there are too few "heroes" left to stand against them. And when they come, they plunge the world into eternal night.
- *Dark:* The tagline for the setting is "the darkest fantasy" and I think it generally lives up to the epithet. Plus it's literally dark: the world is forever in night.
- *Gritty:* The game is fairly gritty mostly due to the consequences from a lack of light, the types of monsters, and the general horror theme. It can be made more so with the Gritty Damage setting rule in *Savage Worlds* (thus increasing the lethality of the setting).
- *Low/subtle magic:* Mages and clerics exist, but are few. Magic exists and standard *Savage Worlds* powers are available, but is generally de-emphasized in the setting.
- *Pre-built:* An entire scripted campaign that leads to a resolution in the setting. It doesn't follow the plot point campaign model of later *Savage Worlds* products, but still is great nonetheless.

## **[Sundered Skies](http://www.tripleacegames.com/brands/sundered-skies/)** by Triple Ace Games

> The people of the Skies survive, tested by an unimaginable apocalypse, struggling daily against ravenous beasts, sky pirates, and the effects of the inescapable voidglow!
>
> But the fate of the Skies is in danger! The magic of the glow is not the only taint in this unforgiving realm. Dark forces conspire to bring the Skies to the brink of an even greater catastrophe. Can you survive long enough to discover the secrets of Sundered Skies?
>
> A shattered world. A thousand floating islands. A constant glow of madness.
> Sundered Skies begins where every other world ends.

- *The Big Issue:* The setting is post-apocalyptic where the world blew up and you now have shards of earth floating around in the magical Glow. In addition to all the mess that that caused, there's an emerging darkness that's about to make things *even worse*.
- *Dark:* Advertised as a "dark fantasy" and fear, along with madness, are important parts of the setting.
- *Gritty:* Gritty in that it's generally a rough place to live and that there are few bastions of civilizations left. It can be made more so with the Gritty Damage setting rule in *Savage Worlds* (thus increasing the lethality of the setting).
- *Low/subtle magic:* Magic is pretty prominent in the setting (the world is floating in magical aether) and there are several deities and sources for magical powers. There are also tinkerers who use the Weird Science rules to create magical devices. You could discourage players from taking those character types if you prefer to limit the amount of magic.
- *Pre-built:* An entire plot point campaign that concludes with the setting being altered forever. There is also a Companion book that adds more adventures.

## **[Hellfrost](http://www.tripleacegames.com/brands/hellfrost/)** by Triple Ace Games

> An endless winter is coming.
>
> The history of Rassilon is bloody. From the frozen far north, beyond the civilized lands with their rolling hills and forests, arose a mighty army of frost giants, ice devils, Hellfrost dragons, and fearsome orcs, servants all of the ice god Thrym. So began the terrible Blizzard War and the downfall of the mighty empires of man.
>
> Five hundred years later the races of the southern lands may have won the war, but they suffer its legacy still. For five centuries the winters have grown steadily longer and colder. Huge swathes of the land of Rassilon are permanently covered in ice and snow, and even the temperate lands are not spared the misery of failed harvests, deadly winters, and the dreaded Hellfrost wind.
>
> But winter is not the only danger. A mere 30 years ago, magic, once the civilized races’ most potent weapon, suddenly began to fail. The Siphoning, an effect of unknown origin, has made magic an unpredictable ally.

- *The Big Issue:* The wold is devolving into an endless winter, magic is failing, and civilization is collapsing.
- *Dark:* While not quite as dark as the other two and advertised as an "epic fantasy", it can still have some dark moments especially if you play up the collpase of civilization.
- *Gritty:*  The rules for cold and other weather especially can make this a game of gritty survival. It can be made more so with the Gritty Damage setting rule in *Savage Worlds* (thus increasing the lethality of the setting).
- *Low/subtle magic:* Magic is failing, but still is very prominent. Generally it's less reliable, yet still a very important part of the setting and there are many sources that players can tap into. Like with *Sundered Skies*, you could discourage players from taking those character types if you prefer to limit the amount of magic.
- *Pre-built:* No plot point campaign exists, but there is at least one campaign (the "Frost Giants Saga"), 20+ official adventures for varying ranks, and the Encounter Book, which provides 50 short encounters. Additionally, there are *four* compendium books and loads of other setting materials and adventure generators, making Hellfrost have more setting support than any other *Savage Worlds* setting.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Hellfrost for Savage Worlds. Low magic, dangerous world (everything is becoming colder and more desperate). 
http://www.tripleacegames.com/brands/hellfrost/

Answer (score 0):

It's an oldie, but it's potentially EXACTLY what you want, and it's Evernight. It's an apocalypse in a fantasy setting and it's War of the Worlds meets Lord of the Rings. It's quite linear but the essentially linear nature of the apocalypse drives it along. Once done, it's probably done for ever, but it's a roller coaster ride.

http://www.peginc.com/product-category/evernight/

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! While we appreciate your answer, it's not clear what this adds since other answers posted nearly a year ago also mention Evernight.